# Why do I get invalid syntax when I try to use pandas to run this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
# Let's create a pandas dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame({
"Name": ['Joyce','Joy','Ram','Maria'],
"Age": ['19','18','20','19'],
"Hobbies": ['Yoga','Dance','Sports','Reading']
"Favorite Food": ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Dosa', 'Idly']},
columns=['Name','Age','Hobbies','Favorite Food'])

print(df)
```

```
 File "./remove_columns_pandas.py", line 8
 "Favorite Food": ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Dosa', 'Idly']},
          ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I get this `SyntaxError` when I run the code but I do not know why. I appreciate your input very much as to why I get this error.

Comment: You're missing a `,` after the `"Hobbies"` line

Comment: @MattDMo Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary is incorrect you are missing the ,:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
"Name": ['Joyce','Joy','Ram','Maria'],
"Age": ['19','18','20','19'],
"Hobbies": ['Yoga','Dance','Sports','Reading'],
"Favorite Food": ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Dosa', 'Idly']},
columns=['Name','Age','Hobbies','Favorite Food'])
```